# Set HTTP headers based upon response code

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

am trying to set cache age for 200 responses and no cache for rest of the calls. I tried below config, which works fine when 200 OK response comes up and I can see max-age=800 in headers

But for other responses like 400 etc. I am not able to see cache-control header itself in developer console. Any clue to fix this issue. below is what i tried so far

```
   <If "%{REQUEST_STATUS} == '200'">
         Header set Cache-Control: "max-age=800"
    </If>
    <If "%{REQUEST_STATUS} != '200'">
         Header set Cache-Control: "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    </If>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

REQUEST_STATUS does not work inside an IF

What you can do is add a condition to the Header directive:

```
Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 302"
```